# Using xe:tooltip inside xe:dynamicContent

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

i have i problem with the `xe:tooltip`.
I have a XPage with a `xe:dynamicContent` control to change the Content of the form table. My Problem now is that this form should contain several calculatet `xe:tooltip` (help for the user).

For the tooltip i created a customControl like this (Code Updated):

```
                <xp:link
                    id="lnkHelp">
                    <xp:image
                        id="imgHelp"
                        url="/.ibmxspres/domino/oneuiv2/images/iconHelp16.png">
                    </xp:image>
                </xp:link>
                <xe:tooltip
                    id="tooltip" for="lnkHelp" dynamicContent="true">
                    <xp:panel
                        id="helpContent" rendered="true"> TEST
                        <xp:text escape="true"  id="computedField2"
                            value="#{javascript:@Now().getMilliseconds()}">
                        </xp:text>
                    </xp:panel>
                </xe:tooltip>
```

This control works fine if i use it somwhere outside the xe:dynamicContent element. Inside my table i get following error when i trigger the mouseover action on the HelpLink: **Error refreshing element: view:id ... some id's :dynamicContent:_id38_id39:tooltipHelp**. I dont get any errors in the server console nor i get any in the xpages_exec log. But i get the two print statements before and after content load.

So does that mean i cant use a xe:tooltip with dynamicContent inside a xe:dynamicContent? Did anyone had a similar problem? Is there a Workaround?

**Update**:
I did some further testing on this Problem now i have following code on my xPage:

```
<xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    var dynamicContent = getComponent('dynamicContent');
    dynamicContent.show(viewScope.selected);}]]>
</xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>

    <xe:dynamicContent  partialEvents="true" id="dynamicContent" defaultFacet="key_2">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:panel xp:key="key_1" id="panel1">
                <xp:link id="lnkHelp">
                    <xp:image
                        id="imgHelp"
                        url="/.ibmxspres/domino/oneuiv2/images/iconHelp16.png">
                    </xp:image>
                </xp:link>
                <xe:tooltip id="tooltip" for="lnkHelp" dynamicContent="true">
                    <xp:panel
                        id="helpContent" rendered="true"> TEST
                        <xp:text escape="true"  id="computedField2"
                            value="#{javascript:@Now().getMilliseconds()}">
                        </xp:text>
                    </xp:panel>
                </xe:tooltip>
            </xp:panel>
            <xp:panel xp:key="key_2" id="panel2">
                <xc:tooltipControl></xc:tooltipControl>
            </xp:panel>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xe:dynamicContent>

<xp:button value="key_1" id="key_1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete"
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.selected = "key_1";}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

As you can see in panel1 i used the same code as in the tooltipControl in panel2 (copy paste) now the Code from panel1 is working but the code in panel2 is not!?? Seems like a bug not a feature can anyone confirm that? Currently running 9.0.1 Server and extlib Version 9.0.1.v00_09_20140903-1400.

Comment: Just tested it and runs fine over here. Server is 9.0.1FP2 on Windows with the September '14 release of the ExtLib on it. Tested it in Chrome 38 (also on Windows). Tested it also on a 9.0.1FP1 server with the January '14 release of the ExtLib. Runs fine too.

Comment: Sure? is the tooltip showing if you use `defaultFacet="key_2"`? (Added Server & extlib verion to the question) hmm... cant get it working already working on another solution.

Comment: Are you running FP2 too? That might make a difference.

Comment: Nope currently not ... i cant say when we are able to upgrade

Comment: Yes, it also shows correctly if I set `defaultFacet="key_2"`. Here's my test page on 901FP1 / ExtLib 9.0.1.v00_03: http://www.bootstrap4xpages.com/tooltip.nsf/tooltipTest.xsp

Comment: Thanks... I think i finally figured it out.. i removed the beforeRenderResponse instead of changing the viewScope.selected i moved the dynamicContent.show to the button event... this now works for me to. Now i have to decide if i change every button or come up with another solution for the tooltip. (Added original Button to Question)

Comment: Could be worth adding your solution as an answer to the question, and marking it accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i finally figured it out.. i removed the beforeRenderResponse instead of changing the viewScope.selected i moved the dynamicContent.show to the button event... this now works for me to. Now i have to decide if i change every button or come up with another solution for the tooltip.

new button code:

```
<xp:button
    value="key_1"
    id="key_1">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:      
            var dynamicContent = getComponent('dynamicContent');
            dynamicContent.show("key_1");}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```